Failed to bundle asset error in AWS Amplify Gen2 Functions
I am working on a full stack app with Next.js, Tailwind css and Amplify Gen2. I created an amplify function and am trying to sync my changes with my backend sandbox in AWS but I keep getting a
Failed to bundle asset error

Can someone please help me out?


I tried deleting my sandbox from AWS amplify but that didn't work.

Came across the same error, and just needed to make sure that the amplifyconfiguration.json file was copied over. https://docs.amplify.aws/gen2/build-a-backend/data/customize-authz/grant-lambda-function-access-to-api/#:~:text=%7D-,The,you%20can%20import%20the%20file%20into%20your%20function%20as%20shown%20above.,-Note%3A%20Whenever
Amplify docs explaining the need to copy config
Import of config highligted

But I am not connecting my function to any data. Its a simple standalone function that returns a static string. Can you please tell me why I need to copy over the amplifyconfiguration.json?

I also met your issue. My suggestion is to use --debug when ran the command npx ampx --debug sandbox. Normally, I miss the library. Therefore, please check all of the errors in debug then rerun again.
I hope this can help you
